# Rounded UIButton-cant align text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIButton in a circle shape(corner radius=width/2) , and i am trying to center the title of that button , to be in the center of the circle . somehow its not on the center, and i have tried everything ,with no success.

I can see the + sign(its title) a little bit left and up from the center.
With letters its the same-the letter title is not centered  :

```
UIButton *menu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
menu.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[menu setTitle:@"M" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[menu setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
menu.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
menu.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter ;
menu.frame=CGRectMake(delta, 0, mwidth, mwidth);
menu.layer.cornerRadius=menu.frame.size.width/2.0;
menu.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
```

Have also tried to set the `titleLabel` alignment to center without success .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to adopt position of the title by playing with [setTitleEdgeInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleEdgeInsets) method and try with different insets and choose which fits best your customisation

Comment: yes thats what i just did,it works, i think its because if you have the border in 1 pixel, he calculates the center 1 pixel left.. i will accept your answer when it lets me.

Comment: Title Edge Insets can also be set via storyboard :D !

Comment: Let it be a circular UIButton which needs `layer.masksToBounds = true` ,but this will cause title not to display.Do you have any advice on how to circumvent it?

Comment: @zionpi depending what you are trying to achieve if button needs to be rounded and too small for the title then maybe you should have a label over button that would let the events go through? does the label needs to be over the button that is so small not to be able to fill the text? probably worth rethinking the design

Comment: @JulianKról Thanks for your input.In my case ,I need a title center below the button, but `round` and `title that center below the circle image` seems cannot be achieved at the same time.